# how to import bootstrap.bundle.min.js in vue project with webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4, vue-cli-3

I got a job to migrate bootstrap project to vue project.

I got bootstrap.bundle.min.js( v4.1.3) and the css file and a bunch of third or self-defined js lib.
I have done following work to import these files.

I use below to import css files.

```
//App.vue
<style src="xxx.css"></style>
```

And in main.js I want to import jquery and bootstrap.bundle.min.js globally.

```
//main.js
import 'jquery'
import 'popper.js'
import 'src/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
```

I add webpack plugin to solve '$ is not defined' (and I don't know why this emmited in runtime rather compile time)

```
     configureWebpack: {

         plugins: [
             new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                 jQuery: 'jquery',
                 $: 'jquery',
             })
         ],
```

I have changed html mark to vue component.
After I've done all above, I still got the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bootstrap' of undefined
at eval (bootstrap.bundle.min.js?6518:7)
```

I appreciate your help for why this happen and how to solve it.

Comment: I try to import module by `import 'bootstrap'` and it just works. So I still want to figure out what happened. If there is no npm package of a third party library, how to import them.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are using `webpack.ProvidePlugin` in your `plugins` array is called Shimming. [Here is the doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/). I think it's a bad practice to use such a technique when you have a powerful tool like Webpack. You don't have the `$` available because you need to import it like this: `import $ from 'jquery'`. So make sure you have installed all your dependencies and import them in your modules.

I hope it'll help. If not just reply here and we will talk more. good luck!